# Characters of $\mathbb{S}_3$

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, characters

Let $\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}$ be a basis for $V=C^4$, where $V$ is a $C[\mathbb{S}_3]$-module. If for every $\sigma \in \mathbb{S}_3$ $\sigma(e_i)=e_{\sigma(i)}$ and $\sigma(e_4)=e_4$ find $\chi(1 2)$ and $\chi(1 2 3)$.

I thought of finding the character table of $\mathbb{S}_3$ and think of $\chi$ as the standard character

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$ to format your question properly. Your question, as it is written now, is barely readable. Apart from that, this exercise is just a matter of applying the definitions and computing the trace of two matrices.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg As I said to my previous question I started studying non commutative algebra some days ago so I am a bit confused about how solving a problem. So, my question is I choose a random basis of V and work on it? If not how do I find the matrices

Comment: Why on earth would you choose a random basis when you're given a perfectly respectable basis already.  Just work out the  matrix of $\sigma=(12)$ wrt this basis. $e_1$ maps to $e_2$, $e_2$ maps to $e_1$, $e_3$ maps to $e_3$ and $e_4$ maps to $e_4$. So the trace is ....

Comment: I thought ei ‘s are a random basis sorry… As I said I am knew to non commutative algebra so the matrix of σ is?

Comment: @ancientmathematician Sorry if it is a stupid question but maybe is it easy for you to sketch a solution for me? Or maybe mention a book where I can find exercises like this one cause I am really confused

Comment: Do you know the definition of the matrix of a linear transformation $\sigma:V\to V$ wrt a basis $\mathcal{B}$? I don't see how you can start on representation theory without this basic linear algebra. I've told you the matrix of $\sigma((12))$, it has four non-zero elements, in the $(1,2), (2,1), (3,3), (4,4)$ places we have a $1$ so the trace is $2$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time but I don’t see why everyone here keeps being judgmental about what a person asks. You could have just write the way I should work on these exercises since you know it and it’s easy to you so I could understand how it works instead of criticizing my algebra knowledge. Thanks for your time and answer again